# PHPExcel not setting row height based on content

Tags: phpexcel

I've been trying to set the height of excel rows to auto, based on the content of some long, wrapped cells without carriage returns.

I tried the approachs mentioned in the answers to several older questions, but none of the approachs do the job.  I couldn't figure out why.

The following is the code I have.  I kept all of it in order to find any height reset that I could be inadvertently doing.

```
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("data.csv");
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
//$sheet->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(-1);
$sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(14);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(50);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(14);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(14);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(30);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(30);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(5);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(5);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('I')->setWidth(5);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('J')->setWidth(5);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('K')->setWidth(5);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('L')->setWidth(5);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('M')->setWidth(30);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('N')->setWidth(14);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('O')->setWidth(14);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('P')->setWidth(14);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('Q')->setWidth(14);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('R')->setWidth(14);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('S')->setWidth(14);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('T')->setWidth(14);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('U')->setWidth(14);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('V')->setWidth(50);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('W')->setWidth(30);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('X')->setWidth(30);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('Y')->setWidth(30);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('Z')->setWidth(30);
$sheet->getColumnDimension('AA')->setWidth(30);
$sheetstyle = $sheet->getStyle('a1:aa'.$sheet->getHighestRow());
$sheetstyle->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$sheetstyle->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
$sheetstyle->getFont()->setSize(10);
//$sheet->getRowDimension()->setRowHeight(-1);

$sharedStyle1 = new PHPExcel_Style();
$sharedStyle2 = new PHPExcel_Style();
$sharedStyle3 = new PHPExcel_Style();

$sharedStyle1->applyFromArray(
  array('fill'  => array(
    'type'      => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
    'color'     => array('argb' => 'FFCCFFCC')
  ),
  'borders' => array(
    'bottom'    => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE),
    'right'     => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE),
    'top'     => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE),
    'left'    => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE)
  )
));

$sharedStyle2->applyFromArray(
  array('fill'  => array(
    'type'      => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
    'color'     => array('argb' => 'FFFFFF00')
  ),
  'borders' => array(
    'bottom'    => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE),
    'right'     => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE),
    'top'     => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE),
    'left'    => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE)
  )
));
$sharedStyle3->applyFromArray(
  array('fill'  => array(
    'type'      => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
    'color'     => array('argb' => 'EEEEEEEE')
  ),
  'borders' => array(
    'bottom'    => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE),
    'right'     => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE),
    'top'     => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE),
    'left'    => array('style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE)
  )
));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setSharedStyle($sharedStyle1, "A1:AA1");

for($xxx = 1; $xxx <= $sheet->getHighestRow(); $xxx++){
  $sheet->getRowDimension($xxx)->setRowHeight(-1);
}

        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="activity_export-'.date('Y-m-d').'.xlsx"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
          throw new sfStopException();
```

If someone can spot the problem I would be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set cells to wrap text - or they must contain a newline (`"\n"`) character - otherwise MS Excel will display the content on a single line

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('A3:A6')
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setWrapText(true);
```

You probably want to apply this to your shared styles, otherwise you're likely to override your sheet style